# Alert object in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object, nested

Consider I have the following code :

```
var Descriptions = {
    test1: {
        name: 'test1',
        desc: 'Clubhouse' 
    },
    test2: {
        name: 'test2',
        desc: 'Pub'
    }
};
```

How to alert for instance all 'name' or all 'desc' ? The following does not work `Descriptions['name']`.

```
  var DescriptionsName = Descriptions['name'] <------help here;



var Descriptionsholder =  `'<div class="wrapper">'+DescriptionsName +'</div>';`



$(Descriptionsholder ).appendTo($("#main-content"));
```

Div style

```
.wrapper {
position: relative;
margin: 40px;
float: left;
width:200px;
height:200px;
overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey; 
-moz-box-shadow:  1px 1px 1px 1px grey;  
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px grey;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `console.log()`?

Comment: `Descriptions.test1['name']`

Comment: Oh God, why would you need to alert an object, if it's for debugging, that's what the console is for.

Comment: `name` and `desc` are properties of objects `test1` and `Test2`, which are in turn, properties of object `Descriptions`. `Descriptions` does not know about `name` and `desc`. You need to drill down to access them: `Descriptions.test1.name`.

Comment: It does not matter alert or console.log. The problem is i need to call the objects ` name objects or desc objects. Every time when i call i get undefined.Please help.

Comment: Use a pair of backsticks to highlight code `;)`

Comment: @megawac How to generalize test1,test2 objects? I have to create an variable that equals the names objects,i mean for every test1,test2 it should equal to their name objects.

Comment: @user2968668 That's a different question, but the basic pattern is the same: Use a `for...in` loop to construct the new object from the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
for (var x in Descriptions)
{
   alert(Descriptions[x].name);
}
```

You can use `for in` loop to iterate the properties of an object.

As `test1` and `test2` are the properties for your `Descriptions` object, and after accessing the value of `test1` or `test2` like `Descriptions[x]` where x can be test1 or test2, you can access name or desc property for same as `Descriptions[x].name` or `Descriptions[x].desc`.

**Edit**

For getting all names you can try this

```
var DescriptionsName = [];
for (var x in Descriptions)
{
   DescriptionsName.push(Descriptions[x].name);
}

var Descriptionsholder = '<div class="sandwich-wrapper">'+DescriptionsName.join() +'</div>';

$(Descriptionsholder).appendTo($("#main-content"));
```

**Updated**

For getting all names you can try this

```
for (var x in Descriptions)
{
   var Descriptionsholder = '<div class="sandwich-wrapper">'+Descriptions[x].name +'</div>';
   $(Descriptionsholder).appendTo($("#main-content"));
}
```

Comment: Please check the changes and reply .

Comment: @user2968668, You want all names values from Descriptions properties in `DescriptionsName` variable like DescriptionsName = 'test1, test2'; as you have two properties in Descriptions object.

Comment: Yeah. in the future i will add other variable for desc. But now i need only this  DescriptionsName = 'Descriptions.test1.name, Descriptions.test2.name' that is to say DescriptionsName = 'test1, test2';

Comment: @user2968668, check the edited answer, It will store all names in an array and will join before concatenating with div element.

Comment: It works fine. But there is another problem. The thing is i need for every div corresponds  only one object name. i have edited a div style too.Please help

Comment: Please check and help.

Comment: @user2968668, Sorry, I am not clear, what you want. You want a div with class 'wrapper' contains only one name, and another for second and then third and so on. And these should appear one after another.

Comment: Yup that is what i want

Comment: @user2968668, Its too late to reply, but I think the updated answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

`Object.keys` takes an object, and return a list off all its properties' names. Doing a `map` over those you can get the values as well. And that way construct a list of all names.

```
var DescriptionsNames = Object.keys(Descriptions).map(function(key) {
    return Descriptions[key].name;
});
```

After this `DescriptionsNames` will be a list of all `name` properties in your original object.

Edit: missed `.name` in the mapped function.

Comment: That will return [object,Object] not the name objects.

Comment: This is a useful answer. Object.keys is handy and well-supported by browsers.

Answer (score -3):

edit :

```
for (var test in Descriptions) alert(Descriptions[test].name);
```

Comment: There is no length in an object